Convert dynamic paint canvas to mesh?
I'm messing around with dynamic paint, and wondering if I can convert a frame from the  results of a dynamic paint simulation to a static mesh - similar to baking a texture?
I found a similar question HERE, but it remains unanswered so my expectations are low.

Thanks in advance.

Yes. Apply the modifier at the frame you want.

Ahhh... I missed the modifier - I was looking on the Physics tab for options.
(edit: I can't select a comment as the solution - if you post a reply, I can accept that as the solution)

Yes. Apply the modifier at the frame you want
